# URL rewriting from a url in querystring to more friendly url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, url, url-rewriting

I am facing problems in rewriting my url. As of now my url is in the form of querystring with parameters passed. Now I want to change that url to a more friendly one
. Let me give u an example

```
http://localhost:59423/SomeController/SomeActionMethod?Id=7
```

to something like

```
http://localhost:59423/SomeController/SomeActionMethod/7
```

or something like that.

Now I now I have to make modifications in the route.config file but I am not getting exacly what modifications

I have added something like this

```
     routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "SomeName",
                 url: "SomeController/SomeActionMethod/{Id}",
                 defaults: new { controller = "SomeController", action ="SomeActionMethod" });
```

I can access now the view if I type

```
   http://localhost:59423/SomeController/SomeActionMethod/7
```

But when i put the url as

```
http://localhost:59423/SomeController/SomeActionMethod?Id=7
```

This should automatically change to

```
http://localhost:59423/SomeController/SomeActionMethod/7
```

Should It change automatically to the proper url . If not then how to do it? And if yes then what I am missing as it is not getting changed

The action method

```
         public ActionResult SomeActionMethod(string Id)
    {

        return View((Id));
    }
```

Comment: Post the contents of your `RouteConfig.cs` file

Comment: I know tha I have to add another  routes.mapRoute. Can you not tell in the context of what I have provided above?

Comment: No, you don't necessarily have to add another one. In fact the default route handles this correctly so I assumed you have changed something. I can't help unless you show what you already have. I also suggest you  add the signature of the `SomeActionMethod` and how you are generating the link in your view.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check

Comment: This is what i mentioned in my answer .. since you've named the parameter `Id` you should name the parameter name the same thing in your action method ..could you post the signature of the action method?

Comment: I have added the action method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many trial and errors I found what I was looking for

As I have already mentioned in my question you can add a map.route in the route.config file

Something like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
             name: "SomeName",
             url: "SomeController/SomeActionMethod/{Id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "SomeController", action ="SomeActionMethod" });
```

Or if you have two parameters in the "SomeActionmethod" then

```
routes.MapRoute(
             name: "SomeName",
             url: "SomeController/SomeActionMethod/{Id}/{parameter2}",
             defaults: new { controller = "SomeController", action ="SomeActionMethod" });
```

Now you must be having a query string . Something like this

```
document.location = "/SomeController/SomeActionMethod?Id=" + SomeId + "&parameter2=" + SomeParameter;
```

Now since you already have a map.route written you can change the above query string to something like this

```
"/SomeController/SomeActionMethod/" + SomeId + "/" + SomeParameter;
```

whenever this url is called it will map with the route information you have provided in route.config file as I have given above. And according to that it knows that you have two parameters {Id} and {parameter2} in the "SomeActionMethod" , so it will automatically render the action method and pass the variables.

So you can eliminate the need for having query string in the url and infact have more friendly url which is in terms of slahes "/".

Hope it helps anyone looking out for the same question.

Answer (score 0):

By using IIS URL Rewrite you can configure as you required. [URL Rewrite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqewG.jpg)